# Power BI report to save data fetching from website daily with last refresh date

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm currently working on a report in which I fetch the data from the website. This data doesn't have any date information, so I'm adding DateTime as per DateTime functionality using the customer column. Whenever data is refreshed, it replaces the last refreshed data with the new data and doesn't store previous day data. How can I store data in PowerBI Desktop after each refresh? An incremental refresh isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have premium, I think Incremental Refresh is the answer. If not, you'll need to do some workarounds to achieve that, since PBI is not supposed to be used as a database.

Workaround: Write the data to an SQL database every time the data is refreshed:
https://bielite.com/blog/write-back-to-sql-database-from-power-bi/

It's a good read with simple steps. There is a video as well.

Comment: Incremental refresh is now available for Pro